# Remove DialogFlow response in web-hook fulfillment

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es

Is it possible to disable a response via webhook fulfillment? I'm using v2 of the DialogFlow API.

I'd like to add a 'live agent takeover' option to our bot -- but can't seem to disable a response when using fulfillment webhooks. I've tried responding to fulfillment with empty, false and null values for fulfillmentText or fulfillmentMessages, but to no avail. When I empty these values DialogFlow simply repopulates with the default text.

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [],
  "outputContexts": [
    {
      "name": "projects/${PROJECT_ID}/agent/sessions/${SESSION_ID}/contexts/context name",
      "lifespanCount": 5,
      "parameters": {
        "param": "param value"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want in this case is to short-circuit Dialogflow directly and, instead of talking to the bot, talk to another person using the chat platform. That isn't really possible.

Dialogflow expects responses within about 5-10 seconds, or it thinks the webhook isn't responding at all. So while you could potentially build a bot that either gets internal replies if there is no live agent, and lets a person enter in replies otherwise, that person would have to reply quickly, and there isn't any way for that person to send multiple replies.

Comment: Thanks, Prisoner, we'd really like to default to the DialogFlow response, but use fulfillment to null out or remove any response messages in some situations.

We've got webhooks, and webhook responses working just fine, it's preventing dialog flow from responding at all that is the issue.

Comment: I'm confused. You indicated above that when you send nothing back from the webhook, it uses the default response set in Dialogflow. That is how it behaves. I'm not sure I understand from your comment what you're looking for. You need to reply with *something*.

Comment: (And if you send back "nothing", it isn't clear how you would then default to a human responding.)

Comment: I think that what he is asking for is the ability for the fulfillment hook to send some kind of a reply back to Dialogflow that would prevent _any_ response being sent on to the user. He would like to circumvent any response being sent at all.

Comment: But sending back "nothing" still doesn't get you the ability to have the human step in and say something. That is the part I'm not sure I'm following.

Comment: @Prisoner Sorry for being confusing. My main question is: 

**Is it possible to nullify/remove/clear a DialogFlow agents response using webhook fulfillment?**

Alternative use case: Only respond on Wednesday
1. User submits query
2. DialogFlow maps query to intent preps response
3. DialogFlow calls webhook
4. Webhook responds: Nope, it's Thursday user should not get a message back
5. User gets no response from DialogFlow

Answer (score -1):

In the Dialogflow, you can scroll down the intent and disable the webhook if you do not want the response served from fulfilment.

Comment: I'd like to use the webhook to disable the replies based on business criteria.